# Differential forms - looking for 3 definitions!

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I am sorry for this type of question, but I currently have to deal with differential forms although I have not heard so far what they actually are, so I have just a few very particular questions about them:
So let $M$ be a manifold.

1.) What is a 2-form?

Wikipedia tells me that a 1-Form is a map: 
$\omega : TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega(p,.) \in T_p^*M.$

This is pretty understandable.

Now, I assume that a two-form is a map $\omega: TM \times TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(q,.,x,y) \in T_q^*M$ and $T(r,s,a,.) \in T_a^*M$ for all $a,x,y,r,s,q$, is this correct? If not, could you give a definition with most simple notation?

2.) When do we call a 2-form non-degenerated?

All I can offer here is this wikipedia article [Degenerate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_form), but it does not talk much about 2-forms, I think.

3.) What are these $dx_i$ guys?

What I read is the following: If you have a coordinate system (collection smooth maps $x_i : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) on your manifold, then the total differentials $dx_i(p)$ form a basis of $T_p^*M,$ since we wanted for a 1-form that $\omega(p,.) \in T_p^*M,$ there is a representation of this linearform with respect to the $(dx_i(p))_i.$

Despite, I have some issues with this(in case that this is true): What is the precise definition of a coordinate system?

When do we call a map from a manifold smooth?

Comment: You are really asking several questions here. Answering all of them might be difficult on this site. It might be helpful for you to do some reading on smooth manifolds. One good book is John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: @PhillipAndreae well, but they are just three definitions..

Comment: This may be quite useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57592/understanding-differential-form

I personally think that when studying all these you must first understand the algebraic part perfectly, say, the exterior algebra of a vector space, and have a solid basis on linear algebra (a lot of differential geometry consists on just translating linear algebra results to their geometric analogues). Once you have these and some basic D.G. everything is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2-form is a smooth choice of a skew-symmetric bilinear form on each of the tangent spaces of your manifold. A 2-form is non-degenerate if it is non-degenerate (as a bilinear form) when restricted to each tangent space.

For a general introduction to differential forms and smooth manifolds see Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. For a general introduction to the linear algebra of skew-symmetric non-degenerate bilinear forms see chapter 2 of McDuff-Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*.